# Steam does not run on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: steam

I've been reading what I can of other people's posts, but my problem doesn't seem to match theirs, so I figured I'd make a new thread. That being said, I may have missed such a post, so please feel free to point me in the right direction :)

I have an ATI 5xxx video card, AMD processor (I don't remember the specifics and do not know how/where to find this information, sorry)

I am running 64 bit, and originally had another users error where they needed to install the 32-bit files to help Steam run. I ran that command line and installed everything, and then rebooted.

After that first attempt where it failed to run Steam, it hasn't even tried to open since. Double-clicking the icon does nothing; typing steam into Terminal only gives the following:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 12.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
```

and that's it! No following message or anything.

I've uninstalled Steam through Terminal twice, and reinstalled again through different methods, whether it's through the .deb file which then runs the Software Center, or through 'sudo apt-get install steam'.

Nothing even puts the icon back on the desktop, and typing steam into Terminal only gives the same response, regardless of what I do.

Any help or suggestions? I'm getting to the point where I'm thinking of just reinstalling Ubuntu, THEN installing the 32 bit information, THEN installing Steam...

Comment: did you try installing from the official Ubuntu repositories? it's now available as the `steam-launcher` package.

Answer (score 0):

You can now avoid installing Steam with a `.deb` package.  Just run the Ubuntu Software Center, search for Steam and install it.

If you get frightened by the "Buy" button, you can check this question: [Can I install Steam without a credit card?](https://askubuntu.com/q/286647/42196)

If you are wondering why you have to use Ubuntu One in order to install Steam, well, me too: [Why do I have to sign into Ubuntu One in order to install Steam?](https://askubuntu.com/q/319091/42196)