# Can I install Steam without a credit card?

Tags: software-center, steam

When I try to install Steam (on Ubuntu 13.04) from the Software Center, it asks for payment details even though it is free.

Can I install it without a credit card ?

Comment: I remember having encountered this. I think you can just click on it and ignore it.

Comment: [Definitely!](https://askubuntu.com/a/905876/225694)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.. Don't know why it says "buy", its a free application..

Comment: At least, I didn't have to use a card. Logged into Ubuntu One I think, thats it..

Comment: Im just sining up to ubuntu one now will see if that helps and post back

Comment: Thanks for that, you must sing into ubuntu one befor installing

Comment: Great! :) Have fun! :D

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

While the only option is to click "Buy", **you only have to sign into Ubuntu One without paying anything**.  As you can see, Steam is flagged as a "Free" software.

Once you are logged in, the Software Center will tell you that it's "checking your payment information", but don't worry, it won't charge you for anything.  Actually, I don't even have any payment information on my Ubuntu One account.

After that, you'll have to enter your admin password and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [the Steam website](https://store.steampowered.com/), download the installer, and double-click. You can now get back to software center and install without logging into Ubuntu One.